# How do you add tags to Product Backlog Items on DevOps using Rest API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the DevOps API to post Backlog Product items to our DevOps.

I know the reference names for title (`"path": "/fields/System.Title"`), description (`path": "/fields/System.Description"`), and comments (`"path": "/fields/System.History"`).

But I can't find anything on tags in the documentation. I tried `"path": "/fields/System.Tags"` and `"/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Tags"`, but to no avail.

Does anyone know the correct path?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you are creating or updating a work item through the Azure DevOps Rest Api, you can use the following JSON format to add tags in your Post / Update request:

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "Title of the work item"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Tags",
        "value": "Tag1; Tag2"
    }
]
```

Be sure you add a `;` between the tags

---

Beside this be aware that Azure DevOps is working on additional Tags API in version 6.0 (preview)

[Reference to additional Tags Api's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/tags/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps saves tags into `"/fields/System.Tags"` field. Here is the doc: [Add a tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-tag)